# How to dynamically populate modal using PHP where the modal is part of a div created through a PHP loop?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have a PHP while loop that creates a `<div>` for every row in the SQL table. Within each `<div>` there is a button to open a modal, that also needs to be populated dynamically in context to each row.

While I can populate the `<div>`s based on row values, I am unable to populate the modals for the same. Every modal, even in different `<div>`s, shows the value only from the first row. How do I fix this?

[image: First Row's value for every modal opened using the 'abstract' button]

#### CODE is something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `something` WHERE 1;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
  // HTML CREATE DIV
  // ADD BUTTON FOR THE MODAL
  // END HTML
}
```

Comment: _that creates...?... for every row_ - _Within each... ? ... there is_ - _I can populate the ... ? ...'s_ - _even in different... ? ... shows_ - A guessing game?

Comment: I got your back @Sam. Welcome to Stack Overflow as a contributor.

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest creating modals for each row. It would make your HTML full of static content (big size, slower page loading).

I would suggest the following approach, it's more 'professional' in many ways. You would need basic knowledge of javascript to manipulate your page.

---

I would suggest you create only one modal with unique id "samsmodal", for instance.

And you would write your HTML rows using PHP on the server side. That's already what you are doing.

Then, for each button, you are going to show the same modal #samsmodal. I supposed you would use javascript (client side) to show your modal anyways, right? Have you heard of jQuery or other Javascript professional library that would make your manipulations easier and maybe even add some cool animations to it?

Alright, so, for each row, your button should call this javascript function.  This function would show the modal and manipulate/edit/change the information on the modal.

Please, let me know a little bit more about your situation so I can help better.

## If you really want to write all modals with different content:

You would need to write your modals within your 'while loop'. But I wonder how you are showing the modal. Is it with css and js manipulation?

Comment: So the modal is a bootstrap modal, and it has animations any way. I am using css to execute the modal (using data-target). So what I have is basically  1 DIV (with few fields that are to be populated using data from an sql table)  There is 1 BUTTON that opens the modal within DIV.

Now this 1 DIV is inside a php loop so it keeps getting executed for every value in the row.  So all other fields get filled with new row values every time, but the same is not happening for the modal..
(Try looking at the image in the question it might be helpful to understand what I am trying to say.) Thanks :)